# Insertion in table becomes slower towards the end

Tags: sql-server

This question is out of curiosity. I have a table in which I am inserting a lot of data. Now what happens is this - as the data in this table grows, the insertion becomes slower and slower. What could be the reasons for this? And what can I do for this situation?

There are no indexes on this table.

Thanks

Comment: add an index :) some of your concerns may already be addressed here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/95f1840a-5522-4078-8582-cbd06332d168/insert-performance-vs-table-size?forum=sqldataaccess

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Adding an index is often contrary to highly transactional system and I am not sure this will have the desired impact.  Possibly if there are any foreign keys it is possible the speed will benefit.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne well of course first add that index in a testing environment (cloned db not in production) and let the most hurting [but also other] queries run against it, that should make you safe ;)

Comment: are you using indexes on your table? from what i've understand, if you are indeed using some indexes on your table, then the dbms has to update index's data structure for each new record that you insert in your table. as your table gets larger, this process gets slower. this is basically a trade-off between having faster reads by using indexes but maintaining these indexes become costly when your table gets modified a lot. just a guess.

Comment: @ultrajohn afaik there are no tables in sql that have no index at all, but in common language use what op is implying is that he did not explicitly add any indexes to that table

Comment: @ultrajohn - I am not using any indexes on this table. This table is just intermediate table for the sole purpose of inserting data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, and up to the minute backups are not important, set your database type to SIMPLE (SQL Database Properties).  It could be the transaction log growing and causing you to run through the whole thing.

Comment: Do you have a link for this? what exactly does database type SIMPLE do? (in contrast to "non"-simple)

Comment: Depending on Express vs. Full, your default database model is full or simple.  It is Simple vs. Full vs. Bulk.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175987(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: SIMPLE will do less transactional logging

Answer (score 2):

here's my take on this issue:

Are you using indexes on your table? From what I have read, if you are indeed using some indexes on your table, then the dbms has to update the index's data structure for each new record that you insert in your table. as your table gets larger, this process gets slower. this is basically a trade-off between having faster reads by using indexes but maintaining these indexes become costly when your table gets modified a lot.

this [article](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0020181.html) provides more information about this.

Comment: It was mentioned that there are no indexes, although it might be possible that the original poster forgot that a primary key is also an index.

Comment: the primary index on the primary key is still indeed an index.

Comment: no primary key. I am just using Id int identity(1,1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at speculating:

When you make changes to a database, the results are not written directly to permanent storage — the changes are done to the pages in memory and only the transaction log is written.

After a while, the database system will run out of clean pages in the memory to write to: that's when it will start flushing out the table pages to disk.

There is nothing you can do about this behaviour, it is totally intentional.